# Let $R$ be a ring except that addition and multiplication in $R$ are not assumed to be commutative. Show that addition must be commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring except that addition and multiplication in $R$ are not assumed to be commutative. Show that addition must be commutative.

(Hint : for $a,b,c,d \in R$ look at $(a+b)(c+d)$)

The question is not very clear to me, especially the first statement and haven't been able to make much progress, looking for some hints to finish the proof.

Comment: The question is answered to death by Andrew Ursitti in the linked question, even considering rings without identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a,b \in R$. Look at $$x := (1+1) (a+b).$$
On the one hand, this is equal to $x=(1+1)a + (1+1)b$.
On the other hand, this is equal to $x=1(a+b) + 1(a+b)$.

If you develop these two expressions, you will get $a+b=b+a$ as desired.

Comment: I don't get it. I get as far as $(a+a)+(b+b)=(a+b)+(a+b)$ but then I'm stuck.

Comment: Try simplifying the expression, keeping in mind that the addition is not (known to be) abelian.

Comment: @MCT Oh yeah, I can do it. I'd forgotten that I was allowed to use that "$+$" is associative.

Answer (score 2):

As Watson points out, considering $(1+1)(a+b)$ and simplifying proves the ring to be abelian.

Remark that, in a non-unital ring, the addition need not be abelian. Take your favorite non-abelian group $G$, denote its group law by $\cdot$, and denote the "ring multiplication" $\circ : G \times G \to G$ by just $(x, y) \mapsto e_G$. This is easily verified to be a rng, with non-abelian addition (although it does have commutative multiplication)

Comment: I think the terminology here is incorrectly used. A ring in which the underlying $+$ group is not abelian is called a *nearring* not a *rng*. Rng just means no identity is assumed (but the underlying group is still abelian.)  Btw, an *abelian ring* commonly means that the ring is either *commutative* or else its idempotents are all central.

Comment: @rschwieb I guess it was unclear. I meant "if you take OP's premise, replacing occurrences of the word "Ring" with "non-unital Ring", then the result does not necessarily hold." In particular, the assumption of the existence of 1 in the Watson's proof is necessary.